# Header into Column Pandas Dataframes - Index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Name   Jan  Feb  Mar
A      10   12   13
B      09   11   15
C      07   15   16
```

I would like to convert the above dataframe into the following:

```
Jan  A  10
     B  09
     C  07
Feb  A  12
     B  11
     C  15
Mar  A  13
     B  15
     C  16
```

I think groupby is what I want to use but I can't figure out how to groupby column values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `Name` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
s = df.set_index('Name').unstack()
print (s)

     Name
Jan  A       10
     B        9
     C        7
Feb  A       12
     B       11
     C       15
Mar  A       13
     B       15
     C       16
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)'ing on `Name`

```
In [52]: df.set_index('Name').unstack()
Out[52]:
     Name
Jan  A       10
     B        9
     C        7
Feb  A       12
     B       11
     C       15
Mar  A       13
     B       15
     C       16
dtype: int64
```